# Bad request error i while posting data n angular

Tags: html, css, angular

When I click on send post it gives 400(Bad request )
I will appreciate if someone resolves this

My API is http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas

My app.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post} from './post.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './get.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get.component.scss']
})
export class GetComponent implements OnInit {
  loadedPosts = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCreatePost(postData: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    domain: string;
    description: string;
  }) {
    // Send Http request
    this.http.post('https://hamaaa-ff9ee.firebaseio.com/post.json', postData).subscribe(responseData => { console.log(responseData)} );
  }

}
```

my app.component.html

```html
<form>
<div  class="form-group pt-5">
  <label for="id"  >Id:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="domain">Domain:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="domain" ngModel name="domain">
</div>

  <input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
  <button type="button" (click)="onUpload()"  >UPLOAD</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreatePost()">SEND POST</button>

</form>
```

my post.model.ts

```html
export interface Post {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  domain: string;
  description: string;

}
```

Please, someone tell me what I am doing wrong here
I will appreciate if someone resolves this error

Answer (score 1):

The 400 Bad Request is due to the incorrect object you are sending from UI to API. 
It should be same object format as your API's Object.

The API http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas gives the format as follows.

```
{
"id" : ..,
"name" : ..,
"description" : ..,
"domain" : ..,
"picture" : ..
}
```

But UI is not sending picture field in the request.
So probably check the object format you are sending whether it matches with API's Object.

Also verify the **content type** on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

> Please find the `HTTP` described error code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) By MDN.
>
> Please find the refactored code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9lkzzl).

In your case it is hard for us to tell with out the REST API code of the relevant endpoint code. Since because of that I suggest you to either post here the `REST` endpoint code or Check the post body you are sending and its `headers` such as `Content-Type` and the expected model of the post body in rest endpoint.

Another observe I made looking at the post endpoint is it isnt expecting an `object` it expects an `object array`. Also your UI is missing `picture` field also.

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Emardborough",
          "description": "Modi exercitationem voluptas odit veritatis ut. Non itaque quo est neque nostrum. Officia et qui natus et praesentium odit.",
          "domain": "weber.org",
          "picture": "Your base64 image here"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Emardborough",
          "description": "Modi exercitationem voluptas odit veritatis ut. Non itaque quo est neque nostrum. Officia et qui natus et praesentium odit.",
          "domain": "weber.org",
          "picture": "Your base64 image here"
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you could pass it as a object array it would work.
So your `onCreatePost` method should pass model like `ApiModel` below to API, **Not a** `ApiDataModel` object.

```
export class ApiModel {
  data: ApiDataModel[]
};

export class ApiDataModel{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  domain: string;
  picture: string;
}
```

Refactor your `onCreatePost` below like this :

**Models :**

```
export class ApiModel {
  data: ApiDataModel[];
}

export class ApiDataModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  domain: string;
  picture: string;
}
```

**onCreatePost method :**

```
let apimodel = new ApiModel();
let apidatamodel = new ApiDataModel();
apidatamodel.id = "1";
apidatamodel.name = "aaa";
apidatamodel.description = "dddd";
apidatamodel.domain = "aaa";
apidatamodel.picture = "aasdasd";
let myArray = new Array();
myArray.push(apidatamodel);
apimodel.data = myArray;

this.http.post('https://hamaaa-ff9ee.firebaseio.com/post.json', apimodel).subscribe(responseData => { console.log(responseData)} );
  }
```